# iPhone app crash with iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

This is an image with the error I get

http://cl.ly/549l

the app works fine with iOS 4.2.1 and with previous versions.
Please somebody tell me what it mean!

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, its strange error, but when it occurs, when loading a specific view controller or just at very start up of app. can you mention please?

Comment: NDA. Do you speak it? This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: ok,app goes crash if i run my app directly on the device and works fine if i click "build and run" from Xcode

Comment: The link (which makes up most of your question) is broken. If you can fix that by uploading the image here, let us know and we'll re-open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a full uninstall of the Xcode developer tools and reinstall the final version.  Something got messed up with your install and you need to do a complete reinstall.

Read the `About Xcode and the iOS SDK` in the Developer folder for instructions on how to remove, or you can just use this terminal command to start the uninstall:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all
```

where `<Xcode>` is your developer directory.  In my case it'd be `/Developer/...`.

Once uninstalled, go back and delete the whole Developer folder to complete the removal.  Restart and reinstall.  This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compile for 4.3 in Xcode 4?

Try using Xcode 3.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your simulator or restart your device.

This solve a lot of problems.

Comment: i have already restarted my device and the simulator but i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PRODUCT_NAME` is correct?
It's the same of your bundle?

Target -> Info -> Build -> PRODUCT_NAME

Comment: yes, product_name is correct.